# winsound not found in Python

Tags: python, windows, audio, cygwin

I have this error. Can anyone advise?

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 18:05:38)
[GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import winsound
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named winsound
>>>
```

Comment: What is your os and how did you install python? This module is windows only.

Comment: It is python on `cygwin` (on windows).

Comment: Download and install the pre-built Windows installer for Python, it includes the `winsound` module (the 32-bit version does, anyway).

Comment: I would have 2 versions of python on my machine then? It would be a mess. Would it be possible if there is a link to install `python-winsound` import package itself?

Comment: Are you using an Linux system?

Answer (score 3):

I've two `python` version installed on my windows laptop. 3.x and 2.7.x There will not be any issue as long as:

1. You install two version in different folders
2. Setup windows `PATH` variable correctly for each Python version.

I have seen from my own experience that better option is to remove PATH for python not in use. For example I am not using 3.x so I removed PATH for it. You can always set it up later

[Python for windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)  has MSI installer that has winsound built in (same way I installed).

Alternately, If you don't wish to install another version of PYTHON and then you may want to look at alternative to `winsound`.
I am assuming you need to use winsound in order to play an audio sound.
In that case you can look at other modules that play sound file and use existing `python on cygwin.`
Some of them are
[pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)   `pip install pydub`

[pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)
`pip install pyaudio`

[pygame](http://pygame.org/hifi.html)
`pip install pygame`

Comment: $ pip install pygame

`Collecting pygame
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame`

Comment: $pip install pyaudio

`#include "portaudio.h"
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-9Q9Sel/pyaudio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NLGiMJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9Q9Sel/pyaudio/`