# How to install the winsound library over an Anaconda installation

Tags: python, anaconda, winsound

I installed Anaconda on a Windows machine. It turns out that the installation does not include the `winsound` library. How can I install it over the Anaconda installation?

Comment: Probably like any other library; `conda install winsound`

Comment: @roganjosh I get: `PackagesNotFoundError`. It seems winsound is not included at all in anaconda.

Comment: Then you can _possibly_ use `pip install`. I do it all the time, but I have my anaconda installation as my python path too

Comment: @roganjosh Now I'm getting: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winsound (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for winsound`

Comment: It looks like `winsound` is part of the standard library, no?

Comment: [Check This Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108901/winsound-not-found-in-python)
Looks like winsound comes installed by default, and is not available for download via pip or conda install, if you are using anaconda, you can see where it is by using `conda index winsound`

Comment: This library, though I've never used it, is ringing bells in my head. I'm trying to find the reference I'm thinking of

Comment: For what it’s worth, it also looks like there are plenty of alternatives to `winsound`.

Comment: My Google-foo has failed. I can't find any conda-specific caveats for why you don't have it installed already sorry

Comment: Please include how you determined that "*the installation does not include the `winsound` library*"? For example, did `python -c "import winsound"` throw a module not found error?

Comment: @merv When I try to import it into my code I get: `name 'winsound' is not defined`

Comment: It would improve your question if you included exactly what you did and the output in your question. For reference, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux? Also, the error you described in your comment does not match mine (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winsound'`) which is why I think it is necessary you expand your question with more details.